# shared_ptr as class member

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

It's common to declared contained objects as a pointers to that class, while "forward declarating" them in header file. This in order to reduce physical dependencies in code.

For example

```
class B;  // forward declaration   

class A {
   private:
      B* pB;
};
```

Would it be good idea to declare such a member as shared_ptr, instead of naked pointer?

I would prefer scoped_ptr, but AFAIK it it won't be in standard.

Comment: If you need shared pointer semantics - why not? I'm not clear what you are actually asking here.

Comment: I don't need shared pointer semantic. Since I declare B to be a pointer to B (to reduce phisical dependencies of classes class A), I need to create  B by calling new. Therefore I need to delete it in A's d-tor. It's not much work, but the question if using shared_ptr here, to take care of B deallocation, is a good proctice or not.

Comment: @idimba: if you don't need what a shared pointer has to offer, why would you use one? If you don't need what a pointer has to offer, don't use one of those either. A pretty good rule of thumb is to not use a language feature that doesn't match what you're trying to do.

Comment: shared_ptr / unique_ptr FTW ! !

Comment: Why it can reduce physical dependencies in code.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can (should ?).

This is a *common practice*. As you stated it avoids the need to explicitely call delete().

You can go even further. Here is an example:

```
class RSAKey
{
  public:

    RSAKey();

  private:

    shared_ptr<RSA> d_rsa; // A pointer to a RSA structure from OpenSSL
}
```

Which I initialize like this:

```
RSAKey::RSAKey()
{
  RSA* rsa = RSA_generate_key(1024, 1, NULL, NULL);

  if (NULL == rsa) throw DummyException();

  d_rsa.reset(rsa, RSA_free); // Note the specific release method.
}
```

When d_rsa will no longer be used, an automatic call to `RSA_free()` will occur. Isn't that cool ?!

---

### Update

If `C++11` is an option, you should probably better use `std::unique_ptr` instead which has less overhead and is movable.

It depends on how you want your enclosing class to behave in regards to copy.

Comment: automatic member deallocation is exactly my question :)

Answer (score 2):

If this pointer is not passed out of your class impelementation and execution speed is crucial, use scoped_ptr instead of shared_ptr. shared_ptr has an overhead.

Comment: I believe scoped_ptr is not in incomming C++0X standard.

Comment: @idimba, `unique_ptr` is the C++ version of it, which is also movable.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `shared_ptr` would allow you to pass ownership to another object, so that it doesn't get destroyed when your outer object is destroyed. You state that this won't be a concern in this particular case.

The only advantage a smart pointer will have is that you won't need to remember to put a `delete pB` in your destructor. That may be enough advantage for most people.

When you don't need to worry about ownership issues, even an `auto_ptr` will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a composition, yes it is a good idea if you don't want physical dependency. Then your B will be destroyed automatically when A is.

If you don't mind physical dependency, you can just hold the data member by value.

(You can also check for the pimpl idiom if physical dependency is a problem.)